# Google javascript Oauth related 404 in Cordova/Intel Xdk

Tags: cordova, google-oauth, intel-xdk, inappbrowser, google-api-js-client

I have strange error where I seem to get an error 404 while executing google's JavaScript client. The error happens only on the device; not in emulation.

I am using

- Intel's XDK v2807
- HTML5+Cordova app
- Cordova CLI v.5.1.1
- InAppBrowser v1.1.0
- geolocation, statusbar, device, Splashscreen plugins are loaded
- Using Nexus 6P; Marshmallow as DUT

I'm using google's template for oauth:
[Sample Authorization](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html)

I have whitelisted my app's networking, by "turning off" security:

Content Security Policy restrictions removed:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Access origins from anywhere (added in config.xml)

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Setting the above CSP and allowances in config got me past my original frustrations with having an Error 404 on: (Failed to load resource would come up in Chrome JavaScript console) [This error didn't appear in emulation; only on device]

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

This is the only error I receive in my Chrome Javascript Console:

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=file%3A%2F%2F 404 (Not Found)rE @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:508_.Xw @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:512(anonymous function) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:531(anonymous function) @ client.js?onload=handleClientLoad:5X @ client.js?onload=handleClientLoad:8oa @ client.js?onload=handleClientLoad:5T @ client.js?onload=handleClientLoad:7r.(anonymous function).b @ client.js?onload=handleClientLoad:7r.(anonymous function) @ client.js?onload=handleClientLoad:7D.(anonymous function) @ client.js?onload=handleClientLoad:7(anonymous function) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:1
```

While debugging it looks like I'm receiving this error inside the checkauth function:

```
function checkAuth() {
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);}
```

It appears like it's some kind of location problem. I suppose that's due to the fact that while on the phone it's running the pages as file's rather than a webserver serve's the pages like a website ~ like the emulator is doing.If that's the issue; I'm not sure how to correct it.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: can u check build log and see if whitelist plugin is added?

Comment: I'm using the debug tab of the Intel XDK in order to place the apk on the device. I'm not sure where to access the log of the build. I could build the application through the build tab and report that back. Would that be valuable? My understanding with Intel XDK was that it automatically added the whitelist plugin, due to it being the largest segment of the build settings. Thanks in advance for your help.